# How to store image from src folder in react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I need to store an image in react state
but after I try to append a `logo`
there is an error from the server terminal precise
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalname')`

here is some of  my code

```
import logo from "../src/pictures/logo.png"

const storeImage=()=>{
    
    const [fileName,setFileName] = useState("");
    setFileName(logo);
    
    const changeOnClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Image",fileName);
    }
    
    return(
       <form onSubmit={changeOnClick} encType="multipart/form-data">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       </form>
    )

}
export default storeImage;
```